# How long will Monero stack-exchange remain in beta?

Tags: discussion, questions

On the [area 51 website](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106367/augur) it states that sites usually stay in beta for 90 days to gain mass. This site has been in beta for 332 days! How long will beta last?

Answer (score 5):

The site [can remain in beta indefinitely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and based on our current [stats](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98617/monero) probably will be for a long time.

Note that [Bitcoin SE](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/825/how-can-we-get-bitcoin-to-graduate) has been in beta for a long time despite more activity than we have. [Ethereum SE](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/congratulations-ethereum-is-graduating) has just recently graduated, so it will be interesting to observe to see how things change going forward.